# In-place opposite (additive inverse) of array

Tags: julia

In Julia, one can find the `conj` and `conj!` for the respectively out-of-place and in-place conjugate of a complex type object. Surprisingly, I could not find an in-place version for the opposite (additive inverse) of an array.

The main interest is related to allocation as the in-place version allocates nothing.

Here is some benchmarking.

```
# using BenchmarkTools
a = rand(ComplexF64,1000,1000);
@btime conj($a);
@btime conj!($a);
@btime -$a;
@btime -1 .* $a;
@btime flipsign.(a,-1);
@btime .-$a;
```

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> a = rand(ComplexF64,1000,1000);

julia> @btime conj($a);
  3.594 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

julia> @btime conj!($a);
  979.401 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime -$a;
  3.594 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

julia> @btime -1 .* $a;
  3.586 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

julia> @btime flipsign.(a,-1);
  3.588 ms (4 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

julia> @btime .-$a;
  3.588 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'the opposite of an array'? I cannot quite figure out what you are asking.

Comment: @DNF I would assume that the opposite of an array is the array of the opposite of each term. It feels quite straightforward, but maybe it isn't ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'opposite'? It seems like you mean something else, perhaps 'negative'?

Comment: Well, I mean opposite. If the number is positive then its opposite will be negative of course...

Comment: That's not what 'opposite' means, hence the misunderstanding. I get it now, you meant 'negative', not 'opposite', and I see your question has been answered. But I suggest you edit your question to replace 'opposite' with 'negative', because right now it is very confusing.

Comment: @DNF Unless it is a translation issue, as I am no native english speaker, I don't understand the misunderstanding you are talking about. A number may be positve or negative, but not opposite, the opposite of a number has AFAICT a meaning, it's negative does not. To quote a widely accessible source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number) *In mathematics, a negative number is a real number that is less than zero. Negative numbers represent opposites*

Comment: The opposite of a negative number is a positive number, the opposite of an even number is an odd number, and the opposite of a big number is a small number. But 'the opposite of a number' makes no sense. The negative of a negative is a positive (minus times minus is plus). I'm telling that your question *is* confusing and suggesting a better phrasing.

Comment: Jup, it's definitely confusing. (What is the opposite of a matrix? Its inverse? Negative? Transpose? Eigenvalue?)

Comment: @phipsgabler, As I do not agree with the modifications you made, I updated the question by referencing opposite as additive inverse, which is seemingly the most precise definition possible

Comment: Sure. Additive inverse is precise enough.

Comment: @DNF, after looking at multiple references, both opposite and negative seem to be used in english, which is not the case in my language, where negative is only an adjective. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse, https://www.math-dictionary.com/opposite-of-a-number.html https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242918/is-there-a-word-for-opposite-numbers

Comment: Well, it is certainly not standard usage, and highly ambiguous. To me, the opposite of a number might be a letter, or perhaps a banana. And, as i said, after a quarter of a century of extensively reading technical literature in English, I was completely baffled by the concept of the 'opposite' of an array, or a number. In other words, the 'opposite of -5' might be 5, but the 'opposite of a number' may as well be a rubber duck.

Comment: @DNF, it's never too late to learn something new ! Frankly, I think I also read and wrote my fair share of documents in english, and on my part I was shocked that you didn't understand what I meant by opposite, so I guess we're even :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases except the one with `conj!` you are also measuring the allocation of the result of the expression.  This goes away if you use broadcast assignment:

```
julia> @btime(@. $a = conj($a))
  2.409 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime(@. $a = -($a));
  2.386 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The `@.` macro is just a shortcut for "put dots everywhere", as in `a .= .-(a)`.

Maybe your confusion arises from thinking about Julia types the wrong way.  Unlike (I believe) in Matlab, scalars and arrays are strictly different.  `conj` operates on complex scalars, while `conj!` is just a helper for *arrays of complex numbers*, equivalent to `a -> a .= conj.(a)`. In-place operations can naturally only work on arrays (i.e., reference types), not scalars.

Comment: So do you mean that doing e.g `a = -a` doesn't do extra allocation ? Or more likely `a .= -a` ?

Comment: Both of those do extra allocations. Either do `a .= .-a` or `@. a = -a`

Comment: @BambOo `broadcast!(-, a, a)` doesn't allocate. The rest ist just syntax for that; either of the variants DNS showed works and becomes the same (or at least equivalent) broadcast call.